# Getting Total Number of Fields from SQL Table and Plot to Chart Using VB.Net

Tags: sql, vb.net, charts

I have table as shown below:

```
Scholar
ID  Gender  DateGranted
1   M      1/1/2014
2   F      1/2/2013
3   M      12/25/2015
4   M      3/31/2016
5   F      5/15/2015 
so on. . . .
```

I would like to get this number of male and female (per year) and plot it on Chart.

```
 MALE  FEMALE
   3     2
```

[image: sample graph]

> What I have done:
>
> (1) SQL Query:

```
 SELECT(case when s.Gender = 'M' then Count(s.gender) else 0 end) as [MALE],
(case when s.Gender = 'F' then Count(s.gender) else 0 end) as [FEMALE] FROM ScholarshipGrants s
    WHERE s.DateGranted >= '1/1/2013' AND  s.DateGranted 

(2) Chart Code

With chart
.Series(0).Points.Clear()
    .Series(1).Points.Clear()


     .Series(0).Points.DataBind(b, "YEAR", "MALE", "Label=MALE")
     .Series(1).Points.DataBind(b, "YEAR", "FEMALE", "Label=FEMALE")

      .Series(0).Color = Color.Blue
      .Series(1).Color = Color.HotPink
      '.Series(0).ChartType = SeriesChartType.Bar
      ZeroDataPoint(.Series(1))
      .Update()

End With
```

> Result:

Male are not counted

[image: Unwanted Result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below query :-

```
SELECT
COUNT (case when s.Gender = 'M' then 1 else NULL end) as [MALE],
COUNT (case when s.Gender = 'F' then 1 else NULL end) as [FEMALE] 
FROM ScholarshipGrants s
WHERE s.DateGranted >= '1/1/2013'
```

Comment: No, this would produce total gender count  use `sum()` instead.

Comment: @YogeshSharma:- Count ignores NULL values. Therefore it won't count all records.

Comment: Thanks for this. I have also modification in creating the graph.

Answer (score 2):

try change your query script:

```
SELECT SUM(case when s.Gender = 'M' then 1  else 0 end) as [MALE],
       SUM(case when s.Gender = 'F' then 1  else 0 end) as [FEMALE] 
FROM ScholarshipGrants s
WHERE s.DateGranted >= '1/1/2013' AND  s.DateGranted
```